# obtain the number of times that a user click on a link with link_to rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I have the next **link_to:**

```
From <%= link_to @news.url, @news.url, :target => "_blank", :class => "from_url" %>
```

`@news.url` is the external url that contains the news.

This link send a outgoing link to the url news.

I have this controller:

```
def outgoing_links
 @news.outgoing_links += 1
 @news.update_attributes 
end
```

How can I hit the link over this controller for add **+ 1** to attribute `@news.outgoing_links`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really easy way would be to hook up a `click()` event in jQuery on all links with the "`from_url`" class, and that event could call some AJAX that calls a server side method that increments the counter.

Another way would be to make a `LinksController` and have the link actually hit a `LinksController` action, which would update the counter, then redirect on to the originally desired URL.

Comment: Thank you could you write a example? Thank you